# Is there a web application that can notify you ahead of time if a certain weather forecast is predicted for a certain location?

Tags: landscape, web, weather, nature, apps

In other words, it would be a site where you can "subscribe" to certain locations and then have the service email you if the weather forecast matches the kind of weather conditions you are looking for.

I believe a site like this would serve as a valuable tool for many types of photography, specifically in planning photo shoots and trips.

Sure, there might be value in just being out there and shooting even if the weather is not ideal. Indeed, often we are forced to make do with the conditions we are given. With that said, however, wouldn't it be great if you could expect with reasonable certainty your ideal weather conditions, and have it be sent to your inbox?

Just some examples I thought of where this would be useful:

- **Astrophotography**: When is the next weekend night there will be a *new moon*, on a *clear night*, at [certain location]?
- **Sunrise/Sunset**: When will it be *partly cloudy* at *golden hour* at [certain location]?
- **Outdoor Portrait**: When will it be *overcast*, *not windy*, and *not too cold* at [certain location]?
- **Seasonal photography**: How long do I have until the next storm comes in and wipes out the spring flowers (or autumn leaves)?
- (Many more examples, I'm sure!)

So, does anyone know of a site like this? :D

Comment: I believe a site like this would serve as a valuable tool for many types of photography, specifically in planning photo shoots and trips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the channel for weather here. I get an email to my phone for various weather presets I made.

https://ifttt.com

Comment: I think this is a great solution, but could you maybe explain a little bit what this site is and how it works?

Comment: Thanks for the link. This site is very cool, and provides if [this] then [that] "recipes", across MANY services (craigslist, delicious, etc). See http://ifttt.com/wtf. The weather trigger has sunrise/sunset, tomorrow's forecast, humidity, UV, wind speed. It does not, however, allow for multiple triggers (sunrise PLUS partly cloudy), but the value is there. Besides, multiple-trigger functionality could be implemented in the future, since it's in Beta still. It's close enough for me to consider it an answer, but if anyone else knows of a better alternative, I would be glad to hear of it.

Answer (score 2):

For extreme weather conditions (rain, really hot, really cold, snow) you can set up weather.com to send you text messages about it.

http://www.weather.com/mobile/customtextmessaging.html